# Xpath for div with span having a css class get its sibling anchor link

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want all div's anchor link whose span having css class ='block-diff-neutral'

```
<div class="file-info" xpath="1">
<span class="diffstat tooltipped tooltipped-e" aria-label="0 "> 
<span class="block-diff-deleted"></span>
<span class="block-diff-deleted"></span>
<span class="block-diff-neutral" style=""></span>
<span class="block-diff-neutral"></span>
<span class="block-diff-neutral"></span>
</span>

<a href="#diff-58bd7a5666eef4b8a9e91ed8c4214216" class="link-gray-dark" title="file1" style="">someText</a>
</div>

<div class="file-info" xpath="1">
<span class="diffstat tooltipped tooltipped-e" aria-label="0 "> 
<span class="block-diff-deleted"></span>
<span class="block-diff-deleted"></span>
</span>
<a href="#diff-58bd7a5666eef4b8a9e91ed8c4214216" class="link-gray-dark" title="file2" style="">someText2</a>
</div>
```

Here `div` contains 2 subtags i.e. `span` and `a`
if `span` contains a `css` class as `'block-diff-neutral'` only then get the `a` tag's `title` attribute => xpath with this condition is required

Expected output is => someText or file1

Comment: Do you mean find all the `span`s? There are no `div`s with that class attribute.

Comment: if div contain any span with "block-diff-neutral" css class then get anchor tag link

Comment: Now I'm confused - what's exactly is your expected output?

Comment: all anchor whose upward span contains this css class "block-diff-neutral"

Comment: And from the anchor, do you need to extract the `title` attribute, i.e., `file`, or the whole anchor?

Comment: Your markup looks like it is missing some closing tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup looks invalid (it's missing some closing tags) and it looks over convoluted in places (multi-layered `<span>` tags).

However this should do what you want if I've understood your requirements correctly.

```
//div[@class="file-info"][./descendant-or-self::span[@class="block-diff-neutral"]]/a
```

if the span with a missing closing tag is actually a parent of the anchor this would be better:

```
//div[@class="file-info"][./descendant-or-self::span[@class="block-diff-neutral"]]/descendant-or-self::a
```

This will find a div with a class of `file-info` that has a descendent `<span>` element with the class `block-diff-neutral` and then find the anchor inside that `div` element.

To get the title attribute out of the WebElement you would find with this XPath you will need to use `.getAttribute("title")`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Xpath.

```
//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/parent::div/a
```

Or use following sibling

```
//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/following-sibling::a
```

If you are using python use following code and use any of the xpath locator above.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/parent::div/a").text


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/parent::div/a").get_attribute("title")
```

If you are using java try below code and any locator mentioned above.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/following-sibling::a").getText()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='block-diff-neutral']/parent::span/following-sibling::a").getAttribute('title')
```

Comment: Thanks, please explain the xpath used.

Comment: 1st xpath finds the parent of parent node of child node[span] and find child node `a` of parent node[div]. the 2nd xpath  finds the parent node of child node[span] and find following sibling for parent node[span] which is `a`

Comment: The following-sibling is going to cause you problems if the markup is accurate.  The first `<span class="block-diff-neutral">` tag is missing a closing `</span>`, so the `<a>` tag is a child of it, not a following-sibling. The second  `<span class="block-diff-neutral">` tag is nested inside another `<span>` tag so it doesn't have a following-sibling.

Comment: @Ardesco: You might right however I have provided solution based on html input OP provided and both options worked fine on chrome dev tool.

Comment: Chrome is clever and guesses what the person who wrote the markup intended.  Other browser may guess differently :). It just highlights the fact that valid markup is really important and invalid stuff should be thrown back at devs a lot more than it generally is